# Attempting to modify data through a non-constant pointer to constant data, showing different errors

Tags: c

I was intentionally trying o modify data through a non-constant pointer to constant data, showing different errors. I am expecting to show error at the time compiler calls the function function_try(const *sPtr), but it seems it is passing it and showing error to the next step...please check it and guide me ...thanks to all

```
 void function_try(const *sPtr);

 int main(void)
 {
     int y = 29;

     function_try(&y);

     printf("%d\n",y)

     system("PAUSE");

     return 0;

     }


 void function_try(const *sPtr)
 {
      *sPtr = 100;

     }
```

Comment: const is not a data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this code , and see the error , you wanted to see

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function_try(int *);

int main(void)
 {
     const int * y ;
     *y = 29;
     function_try(y);
     printf("%d\n",*y);
     return 0;

  }


 void function_try(int *sPtr)
 {
      *sPtr = 100;

 }
```

The error you will get is

```
main.c:9:6: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*y’
```

Along with the error message , you will also get these warnings.

```
main.c:10:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘function_try’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
main.c:4:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘const int *’
```

Comment: Thanks Barath Bhushan!